# Set ruby 2.0 keyword arguments with attr_accessor on initialize

Tags: ruby

How can I dynamically set without having to write the same code all over.

Right now the code looks like this:

```
def initialize(keywords: keywords, title: title, url: url, adsetting: adsetting)
  self.keywords = keywords
  self.title = title
  self.url = url
  self.adsetting = adsetting
end
```

If the list gets longer this quickly gets out of hand.

With ruby 1.9 I'd just pass a hash to the method. Like this:

```
def initialize(args)
  args.each do |k,v|
    instance_variable_set("@#{k}", v) unless v.nil?
  end
end
```

**But I rather use the Ruby 2.0 keyword arguments. Can something similar be achieved?**

```
def initialize(keywords: keywords, title: title, url: url, adsetting: adsetting)
  args.each do |k,v|
    instance_variable_set("@#{k}", v) unless v.nil?
  end
end
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

```
def initialize(keywords: nil, title: nil, url: nil, adsetting: nil)
  local_variables.each do |k|
    v = eval(k.to_s)
    instance_variable_set("@#{k}", v) unless v.nil?
  end
end
```

or following  John Ledbetter and Cary Swoveland's suggestion:

```
def initialize(keywords: nil, title: nil, url: nil, adsetting: nil)
  method(__method__).parameters.each do |type, k|
    next unless type == :key
    v = eval(k.to_s)
    instance_variable_set("@#{k}", v) unless v.nil?
  end
end
```

Comment: Nice. Didn't know local_variables existed.

Comment: You can also look at `self.method(:initialize).parameters` which will also tell you the type of the parameter (e.g optional, required, key, glob...)

Comment: @JohnLedbetter Actually, that may be better than my answer.

Comment: @JohnLedbetter Elegant!  Could use `__method__` in place of `initialize`.

Comment: ...and I don't believe `self.` is needed.

Comment: `self.` is not needed. If there is no messenger left of a method call it assumes that you are passing the message to the class.

Comment: John Ledbetter and Cary Swoveland's suggestion doesn't work too well with inheritance. If I was inherit from a class that was initialized second method - I get zilch on a child class if I try to pass anything. Works with local_variables  - I actually tried both - see my answer below

Comment: @sawa, note that the above code will not work if you use required keyword arguments (introduced in Ruby 2.1) as the parameter type for those is `:keyreq`, not `:key`. Changing `type == :key` to `type.to_s.match(/^key/)` should suffice.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a working example based on Sawa's answer. Option number #1 is not working right with inheritance.

```
class CsvOutline
  def initialize( headers: [],
                  body: [],
                  folder: 'tmp',
                  file_prefix: 'test',
                  filename: "#{file_prefix}_#{Time.zone.now.strftime("%Y%m%d%H%M%S")}.csv",
                  path: File.join(folder, filename))
    # Set instance variables and attribute accessors based on named parameters in initialize
    local_variables.each do |k|
      class_eval do
        attr_accessor k
      end
      v = eval(k.to_s)
      instance_variable_set("@#{k}", v) unless v.nil?
    end
  end
end
```

now if I was to create a child class

```
class ReportCsv < CsvOutline
  def initialize
     super(folder: 'reports', file_prefix: 'Report')
  end
end
```

Now the child will initialize with the proper folder and file_prefix. If I was to use the second option - they'll be initialized to nil.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Ruby with v2.5 or above, consider using `Struct`:

```rb
MyClass = Struct.new(:foo, :bar, keyword_init: true)
MyClass.new(foo: 1, bar: 2)
```

https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.0/Struct.html#method-c-new