# Assign hash values in a method

Tags: ruby, parameters

Say I have this method

```
def foo(bar1, bar2)
  ## code
end
```

How could I implement the code so that, when I call `foo('hello', 'world')`, the `foo` method accesses a hash, giving:

```
{
  :bar1 => 'hello',
  :bar2 => 'world' 
}
```

Is there a Ruby (Rails?) built in method, or how could I write it?

Comment: Why do you need it? Why not pass a hash to begin with?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
def foo(bar1, bar2)
  names = method(__method__).parameters.map{|e| e[1]}
  Hash[names.zip(names.map {|name| eval(name)})]
end
```

Don't do that. It's ugly and evil. Give me the whole context, you're doing something wrong.

Comment: Thanks, I'll take your advice. I'll come back when I can clearly reformulate my question.

Answer (score 1):

```
def foo(bar1, bar2)
  {bar1: bar1, bar2: bar2}
end
```

If what Sergio mentions was the intention of the question, then

```
def foo(bar1, bar2)
  Hash[method(__method__).parameters.map{|_, k| [k, eval(k.to_s)]}]
end
```

Comment: I think OP wants to auto-discover argument names and pair them with values. Not this.

Comment: I see. The question is not clear, then. If that is the case, then the question becomes close to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18876592/set-ruby-2-0-keyword-arguments-with-attr-accessor-on-initialize/18876738#18876738.